# Grade 12 physics electric fields question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

The question is:

> The initial electric field strength between oppositely charged parallel plates is $3.0\cdot 10^3 \frac{N}{C}$. What would the electric field strength become if half of the charge were removed from each plate, and the separation of the plates were changed from 12 mm to 8 mm?

Relevant equations: $E=\frac{kq}{r^2}$

$k=9.0\cdot 10^9$

My attempt at a solution:

First I did this to find the q:

$3\cdot 10^3=\frac{9\cdot 10^9 q}{0.012m^2}$

$9\cdot 10^9 q=0.432$

$q=4.8\cdot 10^{-11}$

Then I put q into the next part to find the new electric field strength:

$E=[(9\cdot 10^9)((4.8\cdot 10^{-11})/2)]/(0.008m^2)$

$E=3375$ or $3.4\cdot 10^3 \frac{N}{C}$

But the answer is $1.5\cdot 10^3 \frac{N}{C}$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The question said the relevant equation is $E=\frac{kq}{r^2}$?

Comment: Coulomb's law in the non-integral form only holds for point charges. The electric field of an infinite parallel plate capacitor is $E=\sigma/\epsilon_0$, and far more complicated for finite plates (although directly between them, the potential is still linear). Given the potential difference or the capacitance, it would be possible to solve.

Comment: The text book didn't even mention E=σ/ϵ0, so i don't even know how to use it... also the chapter only taught me this equation E=kq/r^2.

Comment: AlphaGo the only equation taught to me in this chapter is E=kq/r^2, so i just automatically assume the question is talking about that equation.

Comment: This problem is talking about a parallel plate capacitor.  Look this subject up in your physics book and read it.

Comment: I read it, in this chapter it only mentioned a few points about electric field produced by parallel plates, but it did not mention E=σ/ϵ0. It only briefly touched on the subject about parallel plate, not enough for me to solve my question thou... All the examples in the text books aren't helping as well.

Comment: Given the answer they expect, I am guessing this is an infinite parallel plate capacitor, with the electric field given by $E=\sigma/\epsilon_0$. Changing the distance between the plates doesn't matter, because they're infinite, and the electric field does not depend on the distance, but halving the total charge will halve the charge density, reducing the electric field by half. You'll note the expected answer is half the original electric field. And just to be clear, the equation $E =kq/r^2$ should only be used for point charges.

Comment: @JackZ , Jacob Austin made a very valid point.  You were trying to use the wrong equation.  Physics is NOT about finding an equation that has all of the relevant variables in it, and then plugging numbers (with no units) into that equation.  Physics is about reading the material enough times (multiple times if necessary) to understand the underlying concepts, then using those concepts to guide the math.  In other words, if you don't understand the key concepts, even an open book test will go poorly.  Also note -  you will have to work a LOT of problems to understand the key concepts.

Comment: @David White , The chapter that question was in only taught me the equation: E=kq/r^2, it never even mentioned E=σ/ϵ0 or in the past chapters.

Comment: @JackZ , you have a HUGE advantage that I didn't have when I took high school physics so long ago.  You can google the subject for more information.  Google hyperphysics, which is a very good web site.  You may also want to find a more thorough physics book.  Something in the range of AP Physics 1 is probably appropriate.  If you know calculus, try an AP Physics C text (e.g., Tipler and Mosca, 6th edition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Background**

I understand that your book has not yet mentioned the equation that describes parallel plate capacitors.  However, if it has talked briefly about them and has mentioned that charge varies linearly with the electric field between them and that the electric field lines are parallel, then the answer can still be reached.  The approximate electric field of a parallel plate capacitor is given by:

$$\vec{E} = \frac{\sigma}{\mathcal{E}_0}$$

This is an approximate equation because it is assumed that the plates are of infinite length, or $l \gg s$, where $l^2$ is the area of one of the two square plates and $s$ is the plates' separation.  Essentially, this means that if the dimensions of the plate are sufficiently larger than the distance away from them from which you are measuring, then the equation above becomes closer to exact.

In this equation, $\sigma$ represents the *area charge density*, meaning the charge per unit area, or $\frac{q}{A}$.  So, we can rewrite the above equation as:

$$ \vec{E} = \frac{1}{\mathcal{E}_0 A} \cdot |q| $$

The charge $q$ is in absolute value brackets because one plate will be negative and the other will be positive.  This $q$ simply describes the magnitude of the charge on one plate, which will be equal to the charge on the other.

**Solution With Equation**

This seems like a classic example of a problem that is trying to get you to find the total factor by which the answer will change.  The simplest way to do this is to look at the equation above, and see that $|q|$ is directly proportional to $\vec{E}$.  This means that if $|q|$ is cut in half, or multiplied by a factor of 0.5, then the electric field will also change by a factor of 0.5.

Since the separation of the plates does not come into play in this equation, it will not have an effect on the electric field.  This is most likely included into the question to throw you off.

Thus, the electric field will change by a factor of 0.5 because of the change in charge, and won't change at all due to the change in separation of the plates.  So the net change factor is 0.5.

$$ 3.0 \times 10^3 \frac{\text{N}}{\text{C}} \cdot 0.5 = 1.5 \times 10^3 \frac{\text{N}}{\text{C}} $$

**Solution Without Equation**

As I said above, if you know that the electric field in a parallel plate capacitor varies linearly with the charge of its plates, then you know that cutting the charge in half will also halve the electric field between the plates.

The more interesting part of this problem comes from the fact that plate separation doesn't change the electric field.  The idea here is that, if the area of the plates is sufficiently greater than the distance between them—these quantities have different dimensions, so it's probably better to compare the side length of a square plate to the plate separation—then we can approximate the plates as being infinitely long from the perspective of the space directly between them.  As we move closer and closer to the edge, this approximation crumbles.

The key fact to realize is that **electric field lines never cross**.  A workaround explanation is that the direction of the net electric force on an object is determined by the net electric field direction at that object.  If field lines crossed, then the object would feel two different net electric forces: not impossible.

Because electric field lines cannot cross, and the plate is essentially infinite, the lines must be parallel.  If the field lines were not parallel on an infinite plate, then they would necessarily cross.  Also, field strength depends on the density of field lines.  If the lines are parallel, then the field strength cannot change with distance, and the lines do not grow closer for farther apart.

Thus, the electric field is cut in half due to the charges, and there is no effect due to the separation of the plates.

$$ 3.0 \times 10^3 \frac{\text{N}}{\text{C}} \cdot 0.5 = 1.5 \times 10^3 \frac{\text{N}}{\text{C}} $$

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me, I will keep this in mind. :)